# How to differentiate orders from Magento website, Andriod app & iOS app

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, mobile, android

Custom made android & ios application has been created by using our Magento source code & database.

Since we are getting orders from different environments such as Magento website, Andriod & iOS app, we would like the differentiate the source of the order.

Please let me know the best way to differentiate the source of the order.

Thaks in advance!

Comment: have you created same store view for website, Andriod app & iOS app?

Comment: Yes. Website, Andriod app & iOS app uses the same store view

Comment: @MuthukumarSivasamy - How you have created custom made android & ios application has been created by using our Magento source code & database. Using any third party app or by own. If third party means then you can the developer to get the different environments details.

Answer (score 0):

To get the different source with order you have to create different store for each device.

And with the help of `.htaccess` file you have to redirect user on different store based on user agent. It will add the store information with order.

Like your main store is **abc.com** and for mobile device you have to create a new store and pointed on **m.abc.com**.

When user comes from mobile device you have to redirect the user on **m.abc.com** with the help of `.htaccess`.

Comment: We would like to differentiate the orders based on .apk & .ipa files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following way:

1. First add a custom field **device_type** in **quote** and **order** table.
2. Then You save the value for **device_type** in **quote**  before placing the order as **web** or **android** or **ios** accordingly.
3. Then after placing the you can easily identify the platform by the help of that field.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about `user agent`, so magento by default does not provide this feature.

You can do it via php in `$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` variable you can get detail of user agent ,

so with the help of this `$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` variable you come to know weather this device is android, ios or Desktop.

In the `sales_order_place_after` event get user agent and save in your database.

just google how to addcutomfield in order in magento you get very good tutorial about that.

Comment: Will $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; differentiates .apk and browser in andriod device (such as chrome, firebox & etc ) ?

Comment: I have try with browsers and it gives me firefox and chrome and all that you can try for apk as well.

Comment: As you suggested, let me try to differentiate the orders $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; method for .apk & .ipa files.

Comment: We tried $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];  to get the source of the order. 

Can you please tell me, how to extract the accurate source of the order like Desktop browsers, Android browsers, iOS Broswers, .apk & .ipa?

Comment: @MuthukumarSivasamy https://www.h3xed.com/programming/php-detect-mobile-user-agent-using-preg-match

Comment: I found order source by using get_browser() method. Please let me know to add Order source value in the admin order view grid next to Order Status.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is create a separate store view to get the different locations. There won't be much difference, except that you can see from which platform the order is placed and the order numbers will start with a different number.

Stuff like stock, accounts and customer/order data can be shared between them, so you'll be fine.

All you need to do in the app, is make it "listen" to a different store ID.